# How to count how many people have same major in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

My question is asking me to count the amount of students within each major. my code...

```
       Select Stu_Major, (Select COUNT(Stu_Major) FROM Student) AS TOTAL
       FROM Student
       GROUP BY Stu_Major;
```

counts the total amount of people in all and my output looks like this

```
STU_MAJOR       TOTAL
---------- ----------
CIT                 8
Accounting          8
BIS                 8
Marketing           8
Statistics          8
```

but i need it to look like this

```
   STU_MAJOR       TOTAL
   ---------- ----------
   CIT                 1
   Accounting          2
   BIS                 2
   Marketing           2
   Statistics          1
```

and im not sure how to make my code do that.

Comment: can you show `students` table ?

Answer (score 5):

No need for a subquery:

```
Select Stu_Major, COUNT(*) 
FROM Student
GROUP BY Stu_Major
```

Comment: thanks, i have another problem with another question but i cant post another question for 90minutes. is there anyway you could help me? it is roughly the same issue again but involving more data.